# Is there a tensorflow way to extract/save mean and std used for normalization?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, normalization

I am normalizing my input training data using `data_norm = tf.nn.l2_normalize(data, 0)`.

The data is of shape `[None, 4]`. Each column is a feature. It might look like this:

```
data = [[-3., 0.2, 1.6, 0.5], 
        [3.6, 1.5, -1.9, 0.71], 
       ...]
```

I understand that given normalization in the training set, the **test set** should be normalized, too, but using the `std` and `mean` from the **training set**. (I assume this applies also during the actual usage of the NN, i.e. input should be normalized using the training set `mean`, `std` before feeding into the NN).

Is there a way to extract/save the `mean`, `std` used for normalization from this function, so I can normalize my test set using the same mean, std used for normalizing the training data?
I know how to save the weights etc with `saver.save(sess, "checkpoints/" + save_id)` . Is there a way to save/load std, mean like this?

Answer (score 1):

`tf.nn.l2_normalize` use the real_time mean of the input data, you can't use this function to use training data `mean` or `std`. 
 [l2_normalize_docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/l2_normalize)

```
output_l2_normalize = input / sqrt(max(sum(input**2), epsilon))
```

Note: Since you are trying to normalize the input data you may precompute the global(training dataset) `mean` and `std` and write your own function to normalize.

Comment: What is a "real_time" mean as opposed to a regular mean?

Comment: as it is computed during the run time from the input data of the function, not restored from any other constant. you can assume it as regular mean also.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert in tensorflow but I am happy to share what worked for me. I made two additional variables before starting the session for training:

```
train_mean = tf.Variable(np.mean(X_train), name='train_mean', dtype=tf.float64)
train_std = tf.Variable(np.std(X_train), name='train_std', dtype=tf.float64)

# initialize other variables here

with tf.session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    # normalize data
    train_mean_py = sess.run(train_mean)
    train_std_py = sess.run(train_std)
    X_train = (X_train - train_mean_py) / train_std_py
    X_test = (X_test - train_mean_py) / train_std_py

    # do training

    # save model
```

When I recover the model later in a different script I do the following

```
# define the variables that have to be later recovered
train_mean = tf.Variable(0., name='train_mean', dtype=tf.float64)
train_std = tf.Variable(0., name='train_std', dtype=tf.float64)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    saver.restore(sess, "./trained_models/{0}.ckpt".format(model_name))

    # normalize data
    train_mean_py = sess.run(train_mean)
    train_std_py = sess.run(train_std)
    X_test = (X_test - train_mean_py) / train_std_py
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/l2_normalize):

For a 1-D tensor with dim = 0, computes

```
output = x / sqrt(max(sum(x**2), epsilon))
```

epsilon is defaulted to 1e-12, or 10 to the -12.

So you could just apply this same function to the test data.

HTH!

Cheers,

-maashu